# Execute async task in componentWillUnmount in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to disconnect a bluetooth device before unmounting a component in React Native. The disconnect is done asynchronously. The following approach is not disconnecting the device. How can I make it work?

I guess it has something to do with the fact that the disconnect is done async.

```
componentWillUnmount(){
   BluetoothManager.disconnect(device); // working properly in other contexts.
}
```

Comment: have you tried creating a promise?

Comment: The "BluetoothManager.disconnect()" already returns a promise and to ".then().catch()" it doesn't solve the issues.

Comment: Try setting a bool value in a loop and set it to false in `.then()` to exit the loop. Sorry I can't be of much help, that's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: @HenningHall Hi, did you find any workaround for this?